# React State and Arrays - Double rendering causes elements duplication

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ethers.js

I am developing a fullstack blockchain Nft Dapp with React, Ethers and Solidity. I have made some routes and a mint page with wallet connection and mintbutton. Under the mint section there's the personal collection, where infos about property and metadata are retrieved from contract.

That's the collection component code.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";

import Dino from "./Dino";

import { Contract, providers } from "ethers";
import { truncateAddress } from "./utils";
import { useWeb3React } from "@web3-react/core";

import { abi } from './abi';

export default function MyDinos() {

    const { library, account} = useWeb3React();

    const [dinosUri, setDinosUri] = useState([]);

    const dinosTD = dinosUri.map((dino) => {
        return (
            <Dino key={dino} uriMetadata={dino} />
        )
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!account) return;
        if (!library) return;
        const getDinosUri = async () => {
            try {
                const provider = await library.provider;
                const web3Provider = new providers.Web3Provider(provider);
                const signer = web3Provider.getSigner();
                const contract = new Contract(process.env.REACT_APP_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, signer);

                const idArray = await contract.tokensOfWallet(account);
                const idArrayFormatted = idArray.map(id => id.toNumber()).sort();

                const uri = await contract.tokenURI(1);
                const uriInPieces = uri.split("/");
                const tmpDinos = [];

                idArrayFormatted.forEach(id => {
                    const uriFormatted = `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${uriInPieces[2]}/${id}`;
                    tmpDinos.push(uriFormatted);
                    //setDinosUri(prevArray => [...prevArray, uriFormatted])
                });
                setDinosUri(tmpDinos);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        getDinosUri();
        return () => {
            setDinosUri([]);
        }
    }, [library, account]);

    return (
        <>
            {dinosUri.length > 0 &&
                <div className='late-wow appear'>
                    <div className='svg-border-container bottom-border-light'></div>
                    <Container fluid className='sfondo-light py-4'>
                        <Container className='wow-container'>
                            <h2 className='wow appear mb-4 text-center'>Account: {truncateAddress(account)}</h2>
                            <h3 className='wow appear mb-4 text-center'>Dinos owned: {dinosUri.length} Dinos</h3>
                            <h4 className='wow appear mb-4 text-center'>Races won: COMING SOON</h4>
                        </Container>
                    </Container>
                    <div className='svg-border-container'></div>
                    <Container fluid className='sfondo-dark py-4'>

                        <Container>
                            <h2 className='mb-4'>My {dinosUri.length} Dinos</h2>
                            <Row className='my-5'>
                                {[...dinosTD]}
                            </Row>
                        </Container>
                    </Container>
                </div>
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

I managed to get the wanted result using a temporary variable `tmpDinos` to store the array of info, because if I used the commented method below `//setDinosUri(prevArray => [...prevArray, uriFormatted])` on the first render I get the correct list, but if I change route and then get back to mint page, the collection is doubled. With the temp variable I cheated on the issue because it saves 2 times the same array content and it works good, but I don't think that's the correct React way to handle this issue. How can I get the previous code working? May it be a useEffect dependancy thing?

Thanks in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to check if `dinosUri` is populated before setting its value.

```
if (dinosUri.length === 0) setDinosUri(prevArray => [...prevArray, uriFormatted])
```

Comment: It will work only for the first element and then it won't add any other items to the array. I can call a function from smart contract that answers the balance of nft tokens, so I can say if array length is minus than the smart contract answer don't add any other element, but again it would be a cheat. I think there's another correct way to solve the question.